# notification about followed persons activities (php&mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, android-activity, notifications

I am making an upload website with following system 
I want to make each user notified if any of person he following has uploaded something new
I don't know how is the design of the data table and if the user has seen the notification or not...
my follow table is like that

```
id | user_one | user_two
```

or i need to make new table?
I need help with explanation or example or tutorial because i am not a professional programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two tables. One table to show who you are following and another table for notifications.

Your "following" table would be a simple table like so

```
follow_id   | follow_user_id | follow_who_id
primary key | integer        | integer
```

This table will keep track of any user that follows one another and it is scalable because your 1 user can have many followers.. So pretend we have 3 users.

```
user_id | name
1       | John
2       | Jane
3       | Mike
```

John wants to follow Mike, so we add a record into our table

```
follow_id | follow_user_id | follow_who_id
1         | 1              | 3
```

Now John is following Mike so when ever Mike adds a picture into your website you will need to query this table to see who is following Mike... (in this case John is).

Next comes our notification table (yours will look different)

```
notification_id | notification_user_id | notification_read | notification_date
primary key     | integer              | integer           | date/time
```

We would need to add a notification into our table which we would query when the user was on say your homepage...

```
notification_id | notification_user_id | notification_who_id | notification_read | notification_date
1               | 1                    | 3                   | 0                 | 2013-08-16 16:00:00
```

Now that we have our two tables we can keep track of who is following who, and when a user uploads a picture a notification will go into your table, and it will be up to you to disable that notification once the user has seen it (or clicked it), etc

Comment: I started to understand the way it's working . I would like to ask you the notification will be generated and saved in the table?

Comment: What I would do is check for any unread notifications, order them by their date (DESC).  Then you will need to code your HTML accordingly..  If you want to store the image you should also have a link in your notification table (something like: notification_picture_id) that is the picture identifier so that when you are generating the HTML for the notification, you can point the user to the image they uploaded as well

Comment: u have any tutorial about how to do it or open source?

Comment: Just doing it all off the top of my head sorry :\  If you are super new at this, try creating some tables in Excel or something and figuring out how you would query them

Answer (score 0):

Create a second table:

```
id | user
```

Why ?

In your case, today, you need 2 followers.
You think  that you only need to add a colum `user_three` if your application need 3 followers in the future.

It's a little bit more complicated than that. How will you make you query with many columns `user_xxxx` ? 
How do you know that user `foo` follows `id` 1 ? You have to verify `user_one`, `user_two`, `user_three`, ...

Trust me, you don't want to follow that path.

In fact, you'll need to re-write your application every time you need more followers.

It's not [sclalable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability)

When you create a new table, you application becomes more flexible without adding code.